# Scraping website cannot access frame element

Tags: vba, web, screen-scraping

I am trying to automate data entry from an excel spreadsheet into one intranet website via vba.
For me there is no issue to open the main page and to insert my credentials.

After this step I want to fill different fields but it doesn’t work for me 

My field has an “ID” but I cannot access this one.

For me it looks like I do not access the iframe correctly and I would need support here.

I have tried already many things but I cannot figure out on my own.

```
Example Source code  

<html class
 <body class
  <table
   <tbody
    <tr
     <td
      <table
       <body>
        <tr
         <td
          <div
           <iframe
            <html
             <frameset
              <frame name
               <html
                <frameset
                 <frame name
                  <html
                   <frameset
                    <frame name
                     <html
                      <frameset
                       <frame name
                        <html
                         <body
                          <div
                           <div
                            <table
                             <tbody
                              <tr class
                        <td class
            <form class
                                    <table class
                  <tbody
                   <tr class
                    <td class
                     <table class
                       <tbody
                    <tr class
                     <td class

<input class="Name Example" id=" ABCDEF " style="padding: 0px; width: 225px; height: 18px;" onhelp="showWimHelp(this)" onchange="" oncontextmenu="showViewerColumnsMenu('AABB45PR','','0','','','',event);return false;" type="TEXT" maxlength="50">
```

Code Example:

```
Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim Doc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim elements As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim nachnameValueInput As MSHTML.HTMLInputElement

Set ie = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

With ie
    .Visible = True
    .navigate "https://Link"
    Do Until Not .Busy And .readyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
```

Comment: Please use the snippet tool via [edit] to insert formatted html code. Also, please include your vba code in line with [mcve] and [ask] guidance. Indicate what error messages you may be getting and on which line(s).

Comment: Recurse the nested frame collection until you find the id you are after.

Comment: How do you download the page and access the contents of it? Do you use a browser component or are you making http requests and GETting the page?

Comment: Hi Ryan, How do I recurse the nested Frame collection? Do you have a code example. I couldn´t find a code that is working for me. Unfortunately I cannot share the page because this a private Website.

Comment: Hi Lasse,  I have added the code